# View function php procedural

Tags: php, mysql, view, count, duplicates

In my module there will be a link that displays the counted duplicate data of every user.

Here is my query for counting duplicates of each user.

```
if ($_POST['submit']){
$query=$db_operation->query("SELECT `lname`,`fname`,`mname`,`bday`,`gender`, COUNT(*) c FROM `user` WHERE `status` = 'ACTIVE' GROUP BY `lname`,`fname`,`mname`,`bday` HAVING c > 1 LIMIT 10"); }
```

Below is the sample output of count for each user:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qu6Kd.png)

Now, using the link for another page view. I need to view the rows counted by the duplicate data.
Below is the sample output for the counted rows:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaB5y.png)

I am using php language and MYSQL for database.
What query should I use to view the rows of count duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is fetch the associative array of the duplicate rows and loop over them.

```
$query = mysql_prepare($db_operation, "SELECT `lname`,`fname`,`mname`,`bday`,`gender`, FROM `user` WHERE `status` = 'ACTIVE' GROUP BY `lname`,`fname`,`mname`,`bday` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 LIMIT 10"
$query->execute();
$query->get_result();
$query->fetch_assoc();

var_dump($query);
```

Change to suit your needs, this is just pseudo code.